# Create test in pytest without hardcoding path of external dependency

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I'd like to write a test in pytest which requires an external dependency. Since other users might have the external dependencies in other locations, I don't want to hardcode them. What's the best way to make these paths user definable?

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def external():
    return SomeDependency("path/to/external/dependency", "second/external/path")

def test_something(external):
    # testing...
```

Comment: you could put them in environment variables and define them in your pytest.ini

Comment: You could also use: pytest_addoption() and add to the parser an argument that takes your dependency